# VSCode snippets change trigger key

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets

How can I change snippet trigger key to `Ctrl+k`? I tried these settings (from default keybindings file):

`{
"key": "ctrl+k",
"command": "insertSnippet",
"when": "config.editor.tabCompletion && editorTextFocus && hasSnippetCompletions && !editorTabMovesFocus && !inSnippetMode"
}`

but it doesn't work as expected, i.e. nothing happens.

I want to have this workflow:

1. type `log` in `javascript` file and hit `Ctrl+k`.
2. vscode looks for a `log` snippet and if it exist then expand snippet.
3. type something at current *tabstop*, hit `Ctrl+k` to go to another *tabstop* point.

For the last step there are `jumpToNextSnippetPlaceholder` command. But I'm stuck with initial action on first step. Can anyone help?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

So, I investigated some time in reading documentation and ended up with following preferences (`keybindings.json`):

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+k",
    "command": "insertSnippet"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+k",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && editorHasSelection"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+k",
    "command": "jumpToNextSnippetPlaceholder",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && inSnippetMode"
},
{
    "key": "shift+ctrl+k",
    "command": "jumpToPrevSnippetPlaceholder",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && inSnippetMode"
}
```

Maybe it could help anyone.

Comment: There is another way to quickly trigger snippets. You can add this preference to you user setting file: `"editor.snippetSuggestions": "top"`. After that all snippets will be display on the top of a suggestion popup, so you only need to hit `Enter\Tab` key to select correct snippet. Horray!